# Installingl YaST on Fedora 17

Tags: installation, fedora, yast

Is it possible to install YaST or YasST2 on Fedora 17, or is it only working on Suse distro's? I have been looking for an rpm or even source, so that I can compile and install.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Ing

Answer (score 1):

That is a really, really, really bad idea. Yast was designed with SUSE in mind, and just *won't work* on Fedora. If you want Yast, install openSUSE.

Also, Fedora 17 is no longer supported, you should really update.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I'm in a class where it was tasked by the teacher of all people. I just needed the confirmation, and yes it bugs working on an out dated VM image after paying 2k for a 6 week class.

Comment: If your teacher is telling you to do that, then it is either a trick question of some sort or you just hard-core wasted 2k. XD